# Linear algebra: proof of $\ker(A^*A) = \ker A$ and $\operatorname{Im} (A^*A)=\operatorname{Im} (A^*)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Could anyone help me with these 2 proofs?

If $A$ is a linear operator then prove:

a) $\ker(A^*A) = \ker(A)$

b) $\operatorname{Im}(A^*A)=\operatorname{Im}(A^*)$

Also is it always the case that if $A$ is linear operator that $A^*$ is linear operator as well?

Comment: What is your definition of $A^*$? This should answer your last question.

Comment: Hermitian conjugate, and i would say that answer is yes but i would like to be sure

Comment: Yes, but what's your definition of the Hermitian conjugate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $x\in \ker(A^*A)$. Then $A^*Ax=0$, hence $\left\langle Ax,Ax\right\rangle=\left\langle x,A^*Ax\right\rangle=0$. Thus $\|Ax\|=0$ and thus $Ax=0$. This proves one inclusion. The rest is very similar.

Note that in general $A^*$ is a linear operator defined by the relation $$\left\langle Ax,y\right\rangle=\left\langle x,A^*y\right\rangle.$$
In the finite-dimensional setting it's not too difficult to prove that such an operator exists.

Edit: In the finite-dimensional setting you can easily conclude that $$\dim(\text{im}(A^*A))=\dim(\text{im}(A^*)).$$ Clearly $\text{im}(A^*A)\subset \text{im}(A^*)$ and that's sufficient.

Comment: Ohh thanks i understand the Ker part now, could you still help me with the other proof Im A* A= Im A*, i am having problems  with the inclusion where i start with x ∈ Im A*

Comment: See the edit for a shortcut.