# Prove that $Im(AA^*)=Im(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let **A** be an operator in a Unitary or Euclidean space.
How can I prove the following statement?
$$Im(AA^*)=Im(A)$$

Comment: On one hand, there is an obvious inclusion.  Can you show both spaces have the same dimension?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linear algebra: proof of $\ker(A^*A) = \ker A$ and $\operatorname{Im} (A^*A)=\operatorname{Im} (A^*)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2411508/linear-algebra-proof-of-keraa-ker-a-and-operatornameim-aa-op)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $\ker AA^*=\ker A^*$. Then, assuming finite dimension (otherwise you need closures)
$$
\operatorname{Im} A=\ker(A^*)^\perp=\ker (AA^*)^\perp=\operatorname{Im}AA^*.
$$

Comment: I guess you mean $ker (AA^*) = ker (A^*) $ in the first line? As we have for $x\in ker(AA^*)$ $$  0 = \langle x, AA^* x \rangle = \langle A^* x, A^*x \rangle = \Vert A^* x \Vert^2  \Rightarrow A^*x =0.$$ Nice answer by the way.

Comment: Yes and  yes :) $ $